# Find the configured line delimiter for a file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Given a file resource, I would like to programmatically determine which line delimiter (Windows CRLF or Unix LF) is currently configured.

```java
IFile file = ...
String delimiter = getLineDelimiter( file );
```

The fictional `getLineDelimiter` method would return the current setting. If a per-project preference was set, this value should be returned, otherwise the workspace setting should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line delimiter preference is stored under the `Platform.PREF_LINE_SEPARATOR` key in the `Platform.PI_RUNTIME` preference node. Either withing the project preferences or the `INSTANCE` preferences.

The following method returns the configured line delimiter for the given resource.

```java
private static String getLineDelimiter( IResource resource ) throws BackingStoreException {
  // fallback system properties
  String delimiter = System.getProperty( Platform.PREF_LINE_SEPARATOR );
  IPreferencesService preferencesService = Platform.getPreferencesService();
  // look for per-project setting
  Preferences projectPreferences = preferencesService.getRootNode().node( ProjectScope.SCOPE ).node( resource.getProject().getName() );
  // avoid to create any nodes as side effect while looking up
  if( projectPreferences.nodeExists( Platform.PI_RUNTIME ) ) {
    delimiter = projectPreferences.node( Platform.PI_RUNTIME ).get( Platform.PREF_LINE_SEPARATOR, null );
  }
  if( delimiter == null ) {
    // look for workspace-wide setting
    Preferences workspacePreferences = preferencesService.getRootNode().node( InstanceScope.SCOPE );
    delimiter = workspacePreferences.node( Platform.PI_RUNTIME ).get( Platform.PREF_LINE_SEPARATOR, null );
  }
  return delimiter;
}
```

The method looks if the desired node and key can be found in the project preferences `node( ProjectScope.SCOPE )` and if none was found, the workspace preferences (scope `INSTANCE`) are searched. If no workspace setting is configured either, the line endings set in the system properties or `null` is returned.

The code was adopted from the `LineDelimiterEditor` that is used in the respective project property/preference settings dialog.